# Semantic-UI: Why is the Body not the same viewport size?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Please take a look at my [Hello World-esque application](https://verumdesigns.com), built with Semantic-UI.

I frequently use Semantic-UI, I like it more than Bootstrap, but I have noticed this consistent issue at the edges. The viewport has some sort of excess margin, notice the bottom of the webpage (blank space), and the right of the web page (more blank space).

I've been experimenting with setting the `width/height` of `html/body` to `100%`, to no avail.

Is this a Semantic-UI issue, or something else in general? Any suggestions to correct this CSS?

Comment: ilrein, I have updated my answer. Check the last three lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because of the `ui grid` property which pulls content outside its area due to negative margin. Try setting it to 0.

```
.ui.grid {
  margin: -1rem; // Change to 0
}
```

The best practice is to wrap the ui grid inside a container. I am not sure why .container CSS code is missing in your site but they have it in Docs.

[**Semantic UI Docs**](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#grid-row-spacing) The grid is wrapped inside .main.container which has a width set.

Comment: _The best practice is to wrap the ui grid inside a container. I am not sure why .container CSS code is missing in your site but they have it in Docs._ -- This is what helped me. Added a container around the grid to solve margin-related issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem appears bcz of the default margin of "ui grid".
To Fix it just add "padded" class to the "ui grid" element.
Just like this:

```html
<div class="ui grid padded">
  <!-- your columns -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set

```
 .ui.grid {margin:0}
```

it will work

Comment: What's the best practise for doing this? Obviously it's there for a reason, I don't want to overwrite core Semantic code, and have to deal with fixing every grid I use, just so my home page looks good.

Comment: you could set `overflow: hidden` on the container div . BTW semantics has it's specific classes for doing these kind of modification , but for a quick workaround you can use inline styles or also create some custom css (that never hurts)

Comment: What's the specific class for this concern?

Answer (score 0):

As Manoj hinted, the solution according to the [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#page-grids) for the main grid is

```
<div class="ui grid container">
  <div class="four wide column">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```