# Create 100vh Container in Semantic-UI 2.0

Tags: html, css, less, semantic-ui

I have a container that I want to stretch vertically to 100vh.

```
<div class="ui grid container">
  <div class="sixteen wide column banner">
    <h1>
      Guardian Family Martial Arts
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my LESS CSS:

```
.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

The problem I run into is that although the banner column attempts to fill 100% of the viewport height it is off slightly at the bottom of the page due to a negative margin on the parent container `<div class="ui grid container">`.

In my inspector I find this:
`margin: -1rem;`

When I disable that style it solves my problem.

Now, my question: Is there a "clean way/special class" to disable negative margins on containers with Semantic-UI 2.0? Or will I need to create an override for it?

Here is a screenshot (the blue area is showing from the div below the 100vh container):
[image: The blue area is the from the div below]

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution was:

```
    .unpadded {
        padding:0 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850500/semantic-ui-why-is-the-body-not-the-same-viewport-size), one should use the `padded` class within the "main grid". Another way would be to apply the `container` class to the main `ui grid` component.